# Fetching with PHP, using with Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm currently facing a problem and i would like your assistance to solve it the right way. Two languages.. depending on it's other. (At least in my case).

PHP: access database, insert, select data.

Javascript: useful calling events without having to refresh my page.

Well.. i've used ajax, but my way seems quite complicated to be correct.

Let me use an example. Let's say that i have the following PHP function.

```
function createDiv($value1, $value2, $value3){
   echo "
      <div>
        <h3>."$value1".</h3>
        <h3>."$value2".</h3>
        <h3>".$value3."</h3>
      </div>
   ";
}
```

My inside my HTML i'm calling this function like this.

```
<?php 

    $values = $db->getValues(); //( Let's say that i'm getting an array )
    createDiv($values[0],$values[1],$values[2]); 

?>
```

Now lets go a step further... I want to append data inside this div when clicking on a predefined list item without having to refresh.

```
<ul class="social-buttons" id="demo2">
  <li>
    <a onclick="letterSearch(this);" >A</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a onclick="letterSearch(this);" >B</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a onclick="letterSearch(this);" >C</a>
  </li>
<li>
```

So, now i'm using javascript & ajax.

```
function letterSearch(element){
    //With this ajax i'm calling a similar function to $db->getValues(); 
    //That i called before to get my values
    //With the difference of the searching parameter
    $.ajax ({
      type:"POST",
      url: "ajaxAccess.php",
      dataType:"json",
      data: {tag: 'valuesWithSearch', arguments: element.innerHTML},
      success: function(result) {
        var jsonValues = JSON.parse(result);
        //After this point i have stored in jsonValues the expected array list that i wanted to get.
        //Now what??
      }
    });
}
```

So..

My first question is: how can i put the data i just got from ajax at the bottom of my div?

```
jQuery.append()?
```

And last but not the least.. Is my approach overcomplicated? Is there any other way?

Comment: if that first bit of php is what you're calling via ajax, then it's outright wrong. you're building/outputting html, and jquery is expecting json. html has never been and never will be valid json/javascript, so your json.parse will fail outright.

Comment: this is what i'm calling with ajax.`$arg = $_POST['arguments']; echo  json_encode($db->valuesWithSearch($arg));`

and my JSON.parse works fine.

Comment: You might want to build a html-structure for your `jsonValues` to append them. Yes you can use `$('div').append(variable)` to append elements to your DOM. I would suggest that your get rid of the `onclick` attributes and use proper event-handler instead (`$('li').on('click'), function(){}`)

Comment: What's the value of `jsonValues`?

Answer (score 0):

IN PHP

```
<?php
    echo json_encode(["values"=>$db->getValues()); //Let's say this is an array
?>
```

IN HTML

```
<ul class="social-buttons" id="demo2">
   <li>
     <a class="letter-search" >A</a>
   </li>
   <li>
     <a class="letter-search" >B</a>
   </li>
   <li>
     <a class="letter-search" >C</a>
   </li>
 <li>
```

IN JAVASCRIPT/JQuery

```
  $(".letter-search").click(function(e){
       e.preventDefault();//Prevent default link action
       letterSearch($(this));  
  }) 



  function letterSearch(element){
      $.ajax ({
        type:"POST",
        url: "ajaxAccess.php",
        dataType:"json",
        data: {tag: 'valuesWithSearch', arguments: element.text()},
        success: function(result) {
          var response = JSON.parse(result);
         //You now have a valid JSON response
          //Append if needed, or loop through and process before appending
           element.append(response.values)
        }
      });
  }
```